# PYTHON 3:UnboundLocalError local variable 'x' referenced before assignment

Tags: python-3.x, function

this code gave this error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment

def predict_price(location,sqft,bath,BHK):
loc_index = numpy.where(x.columns==location)[0][0]

```
x = numpy.zeros(len(x.columns))

x[0] = sqft
x[0] = bath
x[0] = BHK
if loc_index >=0:

    x[loc_index] = 1
    
return lr_clf.predict([x])[0]
```

predict_price("calabar",1000, 2, 2)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are referencing x.columns in the initializer.

x = numpy.zeros(len(x.columns))

In other words, you are defining `x` based on the length of columns in `x`.  If `x` is not yet defined, then how is it possible to determine how many columns it has?

Comment: thank you you for your response. am still a loss, please what am I suppose to do?